# My function takes a string as an argument and prints in a different format. I want to open a file and call my function on the lines in the file

Tags: python

The function for example currently works and would change the following:

13126 Physics 25000 Sarah Jane Smith

to:

Smith,Sarah Jane      13126  Physics     25000

I am trying to make this function do the same to the lines of text in an external file. The lines in the external file take the format:

- 12345 CSEE 35000 Bart Simpson
- 12346 CSEE 25000 Harry Potter
- 12350 Economics 30000 Krusty The Clown
- 13123 Economics 55000 David Cameron
- 13124 Lingustics 40000 Louis VanGaal
- 13126 Physics 25000 Sarah Jane Smith
- 13127 History 35000 Tony Blair

I am trying to call my function to format these lines the same way as the example above. My code currently prints an output but its totally incorrect.

This is my code:

```
print""

# To God be the Glory


Payroll = []
Department = []
Salary = []
name1 = []
name2 = []
possiblename3 = []

print ""
String = raw_input("Please enter the lecturers details: ")


def printFormat(String):
    String = String.split()

    Payroll.append(String[0])
    Department.append(String[1])
    Salary.append(String[2])
    name1.append(String[3])
    name2.append(String[4])

    if len(String) == 6:
        possiblename3.append(String[5])

    print""    
    if possiblename3 != "":
        print "%s,%s %s      %s  %s     %s" % (','.join(possiblename3),', '.join(name1),', '.join(name2),', '.join(Payroll),', '.join(Department),', '.join(Salary))
    else:
        print "%s %s      %s  %s    %s" % (', '.join(name1),', '.join(name2),', '.join(Payroll),', '.join(Department),', '.join(Salary))

print printFormat(String)  

print ""
fname = input("Enter filename: ")

try :
 f = open(fname)
 myLine = f.readline()
 while (len(myLine)>0) :

 # print generates a newline so we do not want
 # the newline from the string


 print printFormat(myLine)
 myLine = f.readline()
 print ""
 #f.close()
 except IOError as e :
     print("Problem opening file")
```

Comment: First, you need to give yourself some assumptions.  Is it always going to come across as `[ID] [SUBJECT] [NUMBER] [FIRST] [MIDDLE] [LAST]`?  What about a name without a middle name?

Comment: yes it will always come across in that format and my code deals with names without middle names already

Comment: In your function, why are you appending the *field* values to lists?  for each line in the file you add another item to each list and the ```','.join```'s in your formatted print statements will concatenate all the items in a list so for each line that is read, the print string will get longer and longer.

Answer (score 0):

If you only either have 5 or 6 words depending on whether there is a middle name or not, get the last element from the split string as the last name, use from element 3 i.e the first name slicing to the second last so you will either get a single word or both words if the user has a middle name:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        data = line.split()
        print("{},{} {}".format(data[-1]," ".join(data[3:-1])," ".join(data[:3])))
```

Using your input lines, outputs:

```
Simpson,Bart 12345 CSEE 35000
Potter,Harry 12346 CSEE 25000
Clown,Krusty The 12350 Economics 30000
Cameron,David 13123 Economics 55000
VanGaal,Louis 13124 Lingustics 40000
Smith,Sarah Jane 13126 Physics 25000
Blair,Tony 13127 History 35000
```

You can also use the csv module to read in and split the data:

```
import csv
with open("in.txt") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f,delimiter=" ")
    for row in r:
        print("{},{} {}".format(row[-1]," ".join(row[3:-1])," ".join(row[:3])))
```

And also use it to write the reformatted data to the original file using a NamedTemporaryFile and shutil.move:

```
import csv
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from shutil import move

with open("in.txt") as f, NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False,dir=".") as out:
    wr = csv.writer(out)
    r = csv.reader(f,delimiter=" ")
    for row in r:
        wr.writerow(['{},{}'.format(row[-1], " ".join(row[3:-1]))," ".join(row[:3])])
```

`in.txt` after will look like:

```
"Simpson,Bart",12345 CSEE 35000
"Potter,Harry",12346 CSEE 25000
"Clown,Krusty The",12350 Economics 30000
"Cameron,David",13123 Economics 55000
"VanGaal,Louis",13124 Lingustics 40000
"Smith,Sarah Jane",13126 Physics 25000
"Blair,Tony",13127 History 35000
```

Comment: Sorry I am struggling to understand how this helps. Also how do I tie in the function i have created. Is this code supposed to replace or be added to my current code?

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to do now but unfortunately I have to call the function that I have created

Comment: @jayoguntino,  the logic is all there, what do you not understand? `" ".join(row[3:-1]))` either gets a single word or two depending on whether the user has a middle name or not, all you have to do is add the logic to your function code

Comment: Thank your help but is there anyway your code could be edited so that looking at your example it prints with four spaces in-between "Bart" and "12345" and four spaces in-between "CSEE" and "35000"

Comment: @jayoguntino. do you mean `print("{},{}\t{}".format(data[-1]," ".join(data[3:-1]),"\t".join(data[:3])))`?

Comment: Is it possible to add a fourth argument to the format structure. I am trying to create this format: 
Simpson, Bartholomew Homer.......12345 CSEE......£25000 
With the dots being white space I want the fourth argument to be the last value in the string. Your code currently puts the last three values together. I want the fourth argument to be the last value in the string so that I will be able to print the white space

Comment: `print("{},{}\t{} {}".format(data[-1]," ".join(data[3:-1]),data[0],"\t".join(data[1:3])))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your function:

```
def printFormat(String):
  String = String.split()
  lastname = String[-1]
  firstnames = " ".join(String[3:-1])
  name = ", ".join([lastname, firstnames])

  otherstuff = " ".join(String[:3])
  return " ".join([name, otherstuff])
```

Comment: You should explain why this works, why it is different the the original solution. Also show how to use it iterating over the lines of a file since you have subtly changed the way it works - and maybe explain that change.